# How to profile tensorflow model to get each layer's forward and backward time?

Tags: python, tensorflow, profile, profiler

I have a model writed by tensorflow like this

```
model = keras.Sequential(name="my_sequential")
model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation="relu", name="layer1"))
model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation="relu", name="layer2"))
model.add(layers.Dense(4, name="layer3"))
```

I am hoping to bdg each layer's run time(in this case, means dense, dense2 and dense3's forward and backward time).

I have get tensorflow profiler by the [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/graphs?hl=zh-cn), tensorboard will export an complex trace file which is hard to analyze.
So I wonder if there are some easy way to know the time of each layer.

Or can I get each operations forward time, backward time and input shape?

Comment: Not possible with current APIs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, is it possible to profile each operations run time ?@Innat

Comment: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/17273